# Move words into next line in textbox tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, input, text

I am writing a code with an input and output with python 3 and tkinter. I want to be able to shift the full words into the next line instead of just shifting half the letters into the the next like when reaches the end of the line.

```
#Input and output fields
input = Text(window, width='40', height='5', borderwidth='3')
input.place(x=40, y=40)


output = Text(window, width='40', height='5', borderwidth='3')
output.place(x=40, y=190)
```

With the above code, this happens:

[image: Half the word shifts to the other line]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Add the option `wrap="word"` when creating the widget.

```
input = Text(window, width='40', height='5', borderwidth='3', wrap="word")
```

The official documentation describes the valid values for `wrap` as this:

> Specifies how to handle lines in the text that are too long to be displayed in a single line of the text's window. The value must be **none** or **char** or **word**. A wrap mode of **none** means that each line of text appears as exactly one line on the screen; extra characters that do not fit on the screen are not displayed. In the other modes each line of text will be broken up into several screen lines if necessary to keep all the characters visible. In **char** mode a screen line break may occur after any character; in **word** mode a line break will only be made at word boundaries.